# Как создать две полосы прогресса в ProgressDialog

Tags: android

Как можно создать две полосы прогресса в `ProgressDialog`?

---

У меня идет загрузка данных из трех таблиц в базе данных. Диалог должен показывать какой этап загрузки идет сейчас (прогресс от 1 до 3) и сколько уже загрузилось в этом этапе (тут размер прогресса не фиксирован).

При чем изначально он получает количество данных во всех таблицах (они записаны в другой базе, так удобнее структурировать десятки баз :)), то есть сначала просто "крутится кружок", пока я получаю количество записей, а уже потом появляются две полосы.

Comment: Похоже что вам надо гуглить secondaryProgress; Вот, например: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10385405/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, к сожалению это не то, что мне нужно... С этим я уже знаком. Мне нужна не одна линия с двумя заполняющимися прогрессами, а две линии...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, мне нужно две линии, как у `WinRAR'a`! Одна показывает общий прогресс, а вторая отдельный для каждого файла.

Comment: это два прогрессбара. Создайте свой диалог. Стандартного такого нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно комменту @metalurgus:

> это два прогрессбара. Создайте свой диалог. Стандартного такого нет.

Comment: Эх... Сейчас заставлю работать обычный `ProgresDialog`, а потом буду кастомный пилить.